# How to select specific text from quotes in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to get values from the other rows by selecting a specifc text from the quotes from items row

Image:

[image: View Image]

I tried all the ways I've know but nothing of them working.. example

```
$this->f3->get('DB')->exec('select tops.id, tops.name, tops.img from tops where tops.items = 1 ');
```

So what I want I want to select that "1" or "2" from items row ( check the image )

Comment: What MYSQL version are you running?

Comment: mysql 5.0.12...

Comment: @atymic can You help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the row you show in the image is an example of what you are attempting to select, then the SQL string you should be using would be:

```
'select tops.id, tops.name, tops.img from tops where (tops.items like \'%"1":%\' or tops.items like \'%"2":%\');'
```

This will select rows where the tops.items column contains either **"1":** or **"2":**. If you are trying to match something else, then please try to be a bit clearer in your question.

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Thank you so much!!!!